# find next comma, skipping anything in parens?

Tags: regular-expression, search

Suppose I want to create a macro that swaps two function parameters.

For example, I search for swap:

```
swap(first, second);
```

And with the cursor pointing at the 's' in swap, I can search forward for the paren, move one to the right, delete everything up to the comma, move back to the (, use '%' to go to the ending ')', add another comma, paste the first parameter, then go back to the swap, and delete the comma that used to separate the first and second parameter.

```
/(<return>
ld/,<return>
h%i, <escape>
p?(,<return>
lx
```

(And I have made a quick-and-dirty macro for this.)

This works fine as long as the first parameter doesn't have parentheses in it.  For example, this:

```
swap(foo, func(2, 3));
```

becomes:

```
swap( func(2, 3), foo);
```

However this:

```
swap(func(2, 3), foo);
```

becomes:

```
swap( 3, func(2), foo);
```

Because the parens in the first argument confuse the macro; it doesn't realize it should ignore the first comma because it's inside parens.

Anyway, my question is, is there a way to search for the next "," that isn't inside of parens?  For example, one way would be to search for a regex [,(] that matches either a comma or opening paren; then if it found a paren, use % to skip forward to the matching closing paren, and then search forward again.  Of course, that would require being able to conditionally loop, which is not really available within a macro (right?)

Or possibly, is there a way to search for a "," after a sequence containing equal numbers of right and left parens?

I was just hoping that something like this exists, given that % exists.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need plugin assistance for this -- because correctly extracting parameter boundaries is not trivial and cannot be done (perfectly) only with regex.

So far I'm aware of two plugins. There is [mine](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-cpp/blob/master/tests/lh/omap-param.vim) (shipped with lh-cpp), and I've no doubt link(s) to the other one(s) will be given to you as well.

Comment: https://github.com/machakann/vim-swap https://github.com/gaving/vim-textobj-argument https://github.com/AndrewRadev/sideways.vim

Comment: Thank @user1685095. And indeed, you're right, in this specific context a plugin aimed at swapping parameters is likelly to be a better fit.

Comment: Like to add [argumentative.vim](https://github.com/PeterRincker/vim-argumentative) which supports argument swapping via `>,` / `<,`.